# How to execute Erlang program in Scite in Windows?

Tags: erlang, scite

I installed Erlang on my PC. 
Then added the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\erl5.8.4\bin` to my `Environment Variables -> PATH`
so I can run `erl.exe` from `CMD`

And now when the the code is typed in Scite
neither of the buttons  **compile** / **build** / **go** in `TOOLS menu` are active.

How am I supposed to run my program?
Should I change something in `erlang.properties`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to the last question... If you look at some other .properties file, you will find some examples of these commands. For example, for Scala, I made the following commands:

```
scala.compilation.options=-d bin -deprecation -Xmigration -Xcheckinit
scala.run.options=-cp bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
command.compile.*.scala=fsc.bat $(scala.compilation.options) $(FileNameExt)
command.build.*.scala=fsc.bat $(scala.compilation.options) *.scala
command.go.*.scala=scala.bat $(scala.run.options) $(FileName)
```

It shows you can define your own variables and use them in the command lines. Just replace `scala` with `erlang`, fsc.bat or scala.bat with erl.exe or other bin (if compilation differs from running), and adapt the rest of the lines.